# Was American Idiot the first Punk "Concept Album"?

Tags: history, punk, concept-album, green-day

[American Idiot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Idiot) clearly put Green Day back on the map, and tells the story of Jesus of Suburbia, his disillusionment with society and government, and was said to be influenced greatly by singer Billy Joe Armstrong's personal thoughts and feelings at that time.  Because of the central theme and the storyline the character travels through, it definitely has the characteristics of a concept album, just like Pink Floyd's [The Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wall), Queensryche's [Operation: Mindcrime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation:_Mindcrime), Genesis' [The Lamb Lies Down On Broadway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lamb_Lies_Down_on_Broadway) and Jon Anderson's [Olias of Sunhillow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olias_of_Sunhillow).

Was this the first time a Punk band had released a concept album?  If not, can you offer up another concept album by a Punk band that came before it?

Comment: In case you would count _The Who - Tommy_ (1969) as punk, then that would be the oldest. Most would probably not count The Who as punk band I think, although they were probably an inspiration to many bands in the genre.

Answer (score 3):

An earlier example of a Punk concept album is [Zen Arcade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Arcade) by [Hüsker Dü](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCsker_D%C3%BC), which was released in July 1984, and recorded in October 1983.

Answer (score 1):

That's Life by Sham 69 was released in 1978 and provides a look at disillusionment in 1970s working class London.